# Frama-C is proving invalid assertions

Tags: frama-c

I am able to prove the following program using Frama-C, which is surprising because 1) there is an assert false, and 2) the loop invariant does not hold (array `a` holds 1's not 2's). Am I missing something here?

```
/*@ requires \valid(a+ (0..9)) && \valid(b+ (0..9));
 */
void test_foo(int *a, char *b) {
  int i = 0;
  /*@ loop invariant \forall int j; 0 <= j < i ==> a[j] == 2; 
      loop invariant \forall int j; 0 <= j < i ==> b[j] == 'a';
   */
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    a[i] = 1;
    b[i] = 'a';
  }   
  //@ assert \false;
}
```

I am running frama-c as:
`frama-c -wp -wp-invariants -wp-prover "why3:alt-ergo" -wp-model "Typed,int,real" -wp-par 8 -wp-timeout 15 -wp-out wp.out test.c`
I see same behavior on both Sodium and Magnesium versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-wp-invariants` is not meant to handle "normal" loop invariants such as the ones you have provided, but "general inductive invariants" in the sense of [ACSL section 2.4.2](http://frama-c.com/download/acsl-implementation-Magnesium-20151002.pdf). You can thus remove this option from your command line. Then some proof obligations fail as expected.

Note in addition that your loop annotations are incomplete: as warned by WP, you should have a loop assigns, such as

```
loop assigns i, a[0 .. 9], b[0 .. 9];
```

Then, in order to be able to prove this `loop assigns`, you will need to specify `i` interval of variation:

```
loop invariant 0<=i<=10;
```

Finally, the fact that `-wp-invariants` make proof obligations behave strangely in presence of normal loop annotations should probably be considered as a bug and reported on [Frama-C's bts](http://bts.frama-c.com/).